# Nginx 403 forbidden to my ip regardless of allow/deny

Tags: nginx

I use the below code to deny access to all but allow only my ip however it deny access to my ip as well.

```
location /admin {
allow 1.1.1.1;
deny all;
}
```

I tried to put a backslash to the end of directory name and other different combinations but nothing worked. What can be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Anything before nginx (e.g. varnish)? Are sure it's your IP? What IP nginx logs to access log?

Comment: Yes I doubled checked it's my IP, I have Apache 2.4 running at the backend. @AlexeyTen

Comment: Oh, well, it probably works, but now you lost all other processing of this url (like proxying to Apache) You should add all proxying stuff to this location as well

Comment: Thank you so much! it works now :) You saved me alot of time. @AlexeyTen